# Pass asp value to the same page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a javascript:

```
$("select[name='selectyear']").change(function() {
  var selectedyear = $("select[name='selectyear']").val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "allquery.asp",
      dataType: "html",
      data: { selectedyear:selectedyear },   
      success: function(result) {
            $("#displayedyear").val(selectedyear);
      }
 });   
});
```

And this (allquery.asp):

```
If Request("selectedyear") = "" Then
    choosenyear = "2017"
Else
    choosenyear = Request("selectedyear")
End If

response.write choosenyear
```

From the #displayedyear div, it shows the selected year based on my dropdown (name=selectyear) correctly, but the output for the <%=choosenyear%> still shows "2017" even though I have change the dropdown selection.

My question is how to retrieve Request("selectedyear") ?

Comment: .asp will get executed at server side and drop down value get changed at the client side, You should do a service call to pass on the value to server.  Changing the value in already rendered html wont update .asp params

Comment: can you help me what kind of service call?

Comment: please ignore my above comment my bad, I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly pass response/result to displayedyear and not selectedYear paramater, Because result is the response you are getting. I have updated it below.

```
$("select[name='selectyear']").change(function() {
  var selectedyear = $("select[name='selectyear']").val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "allquery.asp",
      dataType: "html",
      data: { selectedyear:selectedyear },   
      success: function(result) {
            $("#displayedyear").val(result);//change
      }
 });   
});
```

**Hope this helps**

Comment: $("#displayedyear") is not the issue, i want to output  Request("selectedyear")  based on the dropdown